# Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of 2 x 2 matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Q5. Calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following matrix

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
3 & \sqrt{2} \\
\sqrt{2} & 2
\end{matrix}\right)$$

It is $2 \times 2$ matrix and having square-root value.

Comment: Plz also add the work you did on the problem and where you got stuck. Otherwise the question is likely to be down voted and closed.

Comment: @ Vizag I do not know about how find eigenvalues - eigenvectors for square-root matrix. I know only find eigenvectors and eigenvalues for simple matrix. If you need then I will add my 3 X 3 simple matrix work.

Comment: $2\times2$ is the simplest matrix. Did you write out the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Find eigenvalues from the characteristic polynomial:

$\left|\begin{matrix}
3-\lambda & \sqrt{2} \\
\sqrt{2} & 2-\lambda
\end{matrix}\right|  =\lambda^2-5*\lambda+4=(\lambda-1)*(\lambda-4)$

### $\lambda_1=1\;\;
\lambda_2=4$

For every λ we find its own vector(s):

$\lambda_1=1$

$A-\lambda_1I=\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & \sqrt{2} \\
\sqrt{2} & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$

$(A-\lambda I)v=0$

So we have a homogeneous system of linear equations, we solve it by Gaussian Elimination:

$\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
\sqrt{2} & 1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$

$\begin{matrix}
x_1 & +\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}*x_2 & = & 0
\end{matrix}$

General Solution: $X=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}*x_2 \\
x_2
\end{matrix}\right)$

Let $x_2=1,\; v_1=\left(\begin{matrix}
\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)$

---

$\lambda_2=4$

$A-\lambda_2I=\left(\begin{matrix}
-1 & \sqrt{2} \\
\sqrt{2} & -2
\end{matrix}\right)$

$(A-\lambda I)v=0$

So we have a homogeneous system of linear equations, we solve it by Gaussian Elimination:

$\left(\begin{matrix}
-1 & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
\sqrt{2} & -2 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$

$\begin{matrix}
x_1 & -\sqrt{2}*x_2 & = & 0
\end{matrix}$

General Solution: $X=\left(\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{2}*x_2 \\
x_2
\end{matrix}\right)$

Let $x_2=1, v_2=\left(\begin{matrix}
\sqrt{2} \\
1
\end{matrix}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

We have for the eigenvalues:

$$ \text{det} (\begin{bmatrix}
3 & \sqrt{2} \\
\sqrt{2} & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix} - \lambda \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix})$$

So then we get $\lambda^2-5\lambda+4=0$ so then $\lambda=1,4$ which are our eigenvalues.

Then you can try the last bit for the eigenvectors we have $A-\lambda I=0$, where $A$ is the original matrix and $\lambda$ are our two eigenvalues values we have found. Then you solve this to get your eigenvectors!

Comment: Thank you so much ....!!!

Answer (score -1):

The characteristic polynomial is $$(3-\lambda)(2-\lambda)-2.$$ Can you see how to get that?

Now set this polynomial equal to zero and solve for $\lambda$ to get the eigenvalues. If we let $A$ be your matrix. Then you can find the eigenvectors by solving $(A-\lambda I)v=0$, which you can do by augmenting a column of zeroes onto the matrix $A-\lambda I$ and doing some row reduction.